# many callees with the same set of functions in crossbar.io

Tags: crossbar, autobahnws, wamp-protocol

My project consists in a crossbar.io router with a python component, to wich many python callees will register the same set of functions.  Lets think of a network of IoT light dimmers, each one will register the same `dimm_light(value)` function and return the sensed light of the room.

What would be the best way of identifiyng each one, to be able to call the `dimm_ligth` function of each device? there would be many of them: living room dimmer, kitchen dimmer, bedroom... even different houses, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can register procedures like

```
com.myapp.device.1.dimm_light
com.myapp.device.2.dimm_light
...
```

That is, have a device ID as part of the URI.